Azure DevOps Exporting Test Cases with colums "parameter values" and "Steps" to Excel but they are not well formatted
I need to provide a test cases list to management, containing also the "parameters data" defined for each test.
I am trying to export in excel the column "parameter values" and also column "Steps" defined in a test case,
but the "parameter values" contains only the title and not the real data I used in the test. Moreover the column "Steps" seems not well formatted and contains HTML tags.
My test case looks like this:

I just created a flat query that show also the column "Parameters" and "Steps" like this.
My query results looks like:

The problem is that in the query the column "Parameters" doesn't contains the values i used in the test but only the fields name in HTML format.
Moreover, the column "Steps" is not well formatted as it has several HTML tag that I don't need in the export.
There is a way in Azure DevOps to export the est Cases with columns "parameter values" and "Steps" correctly?

Since the Steps and Parameter fields are using HTML editor for their contents, when calling API/CLI to fetch the content, it will display as HTML type content. For some reasons or syntax rules of HTML, some tags might be escaped.
The work item query feature is calling the API with the filters you set to return the content.

For the parameters directly set in a test case, you can consider to convert the parameters to be shared parameters. There will be a "Shared Parameter" type work item created. When you open the shared parameter, you can edit, add and delete parameters and values.

Then you can query and export the test case and the shared parameter together to the Excel. By this, the values of the shared parameters can be shown in the Excel.



Thanks for you reply. Aniway the "Shared parameter" exported in excel contains the html tags. Also the colum "Steps" after the exporting in excel contains HTML parameters.

@AlessandroCarnevali, As stated above, the contents of Parameters and Steps are designed to use HTML editor so that users can provide the contents as a table. This is by designed in Azure DevOps, and cannot change the format when exporting.

I see your replay and thanks for that.  Aniway I think this is a limitation of the Azure product as exporting the list of test cases including the request data used for each test should be a common activity that is need to do.

@AlessandroCarnevali, If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on Developer Community. This will make it more convenient for the Azure DevOps engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.
